# htaccess issue causing internal server error too many redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

so I am playing with .htaccess to have clean URLs in my codeigniter app.

in short, i am trying to:

1) remove index.php in urls (redirect permanent)

```
http://localhost/directory/index.php*
to
http://localhost/directory/*

http://my.domain.com/index.php*
to
http://my.domain.com/*
```

2) rewrite requests for **certain** controllers to index.php/[controller_name]

```
http://localhost/directory/controller1* 
to 
http://localhost/directory/index.php/controller1*

http://my.domain.com/controller2* 
to 
http://my.domain.com/index.php/controller2*
```

my htaccess file currently goes like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

# Redirect index.php 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php((/)(.*))?$ /$1/$4 [R=301,L]
```

**first issue**:

this does not work for `http://localhost/dir/index.php/controller1`. 
instead redirecting to `http://localhost/dir/controller1`, it redirects to `http://localhost//controller1` (`$1` return empty string?)

```
# Rewrite CI certain controllers
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} directory/(home|other_controller) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(home|other_controller)(.*)$ /$1index.php/$2$3 [NC,L]
```

**second issue**:

this does not work for `http://localhost/dir/home` gives internal server error (too many redirects).
but if I test added `R=301` code, it successfully redirect to `http://localhost/dir/index.php/home`. but this is not my intention to redirect, I only need to rewrite it.

please advise.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can place this in the directory the bootstrap file  (index.php) is in.

If you have FastCGI implementation, you need to add a question mark in the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks @Repox, but this rewrites `http://localhost/directory/controller` to `http://localhost/index.php/controller`, not to `http://localhost/directory/index.php/controller`

Comment: simple... just add it... or set a RewriteBase in htaccess

Comment: @Brian, is it possible to add it by regex without explicitly writing the dir name or rewritebase? so this .htaccess file will be portable for local and production..